# Errors while running Upgrade from the terminal. Can anyone help me analyse it?

Tags: command-line, upgrade, disk-usage

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up linux-image-extra-3.8.0-30-generic (3.8.0-30.44) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.8.0-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-30-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.8.0-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-30-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.8.0-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-30-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-30-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-30-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.8.0-30-generic.postinst line 1010.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-extra-3.8.0-30-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-3.8.0-30-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-3.8.0-30-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.8.0.30.48); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    dpkg: error processing linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.8.0-30-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The line "gzip: stdout: No space left on device" is the key to your problem: you're out of free space on that hard drive partition!

You can run "df" (disk free) command in terminal for fast check of free space on mounted partitions.

Comment: This looks like it could be the cause!

/dev/sda1 233191 208170 12580 95% /boot